# How do install node.js and bower in virtualenv

Tags: python, node.js, django, virtualenv, bower

I'm trying to see how [django-scheduler](https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler-sample) works and so want to install it in a virtualenv.

Having unzipped the files into the relevant directory, here's what I've done:

```
virtualenv env
env/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project_sample.settings
env/bin/python manage.py bower install
```

At this point I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
```

Given that didn't work I've tried following [this blog](http://arcticlinux.com/blog/installing-django-bower-to-manage-javascript-in-a-virtualenv/) and did

```
env/bin/pip install nodeenv
env/bin/pip install django-bower
env/bin/nodeenv --prebuilt -p
```

I get the same result.  How do I install within a virtualenv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered some linux distributions install nodejs not as "node" executable but as "nodejs".

In this case you have to manually link to "node" as many packages are programmed after the "node" binary. Something similar also occurs with "python2" not linked to "python".

In this case you can do an easy symlink. For linux distributions which install package binaries to /usr/bin you can do

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Answer (score 1):

Error talks about /usr/bin/env which is a system command, so can you rename your virtualenv, may be its conflicting with the system command. try creating virtualenv venv and do source venv && pip install nodeenv

**UPDATED:**

```
virualenv venv 
source venv
pip install nodeenv
```

install the `nodeenv` in side your virtualenv, it should work!

Comment: `env/bin/pip install nodeenv` installs it inside the virtualenv

Comment: yes, thats what it will be executed, if you activate `env` with `source env` and then `pip install nodeenv` is equivalent to `env/bin/pip install nodeenv`

Comment: Error talks about `/usr/bin/env` which is a system command, so can you rename your virtualenv, may be its conflicting with the system command. try creating `virtualenv venv` and do `source venv && pip install nodeenv`

Comment: Yes, exactly the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141359/discussion-between-rrmerugu-and-henrym).